# MediaElement doesn't play mp3 or wav

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mp3, wav, mediaelement

*I wanna play a sound when page is loaded. I created an MediaElement in components named "media".
I changed setting as I want and when I run project, notting happens. I can't hear music.
XAML :
    
C# : 
    media.Play();*

**Solution : Just tick to ID_CAP_MEDIALIB in Capabilities.**

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, instead of editing the question. I'm not sure why you deleted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:
I solved this question. I just tick to ID_CAP_MEDIALIB in Capabilities. Sorry for trouble.**

Answer (score 1):

Does your audio file is placed at root level? Anyways change the source to just 001.mp3 and let me know. And one more advice is to keep your media to stop playing any other elements. So try editing to this

```
media.stop();
media.Volume=20;
media.Play();
```

What is the full path you tried? just show us more code as what you are doing to help you... Give a snap shot of how your files are arranged, in visual studio.

Comment: I did as you said. but still doesn't play mp3.

Comment: Tell me where your .mp3 file is? I wonder there might be a mistake with the path only.

Comment: I dont understand whats the problem. Set the audio file to content and give it a try. See this example http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/425685/Playing-a-Sound-in-Windows-Phone-using-Media-Eleme

Comment: @AliAvcı If the audio file is in project folder, then why do you specify the source simply as /001.mp3??? The source should be specified as /Project/001.mp3 and make the audio file to content rather than resource.